# Ng-select: Remote API call doesn't refresh the view

Tags: angular, angular-ngselect

I'm using `ng-select` component (https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-select).
I implemented a way to remotely fetch data when the user types. 
However, the new data will be fetched and the **(items)** object populated correctly, but the view is not getting refreshed.

Let me provide you some code:

Here's the **template**:

```
<ng-select
  #select 
  [allowClear]="'true'"
  id="DropdownTypeaheadQuestion-{{ question.id }}"
  [(items)]="items"
  [formControl]="formControlToUse"
  placeholder="{{ placeholderText }}"
  [multiple]="isMultiple"
  (selected)="execSelected($event)"
  (typed)="execKeypress($event)">
</ng-select>
```

**Controller**: This method is executed on keypress:

```
  execKeypress($event) {
    // When remote, clear all items directly on keypress. Else we have an ugly lag because of the debounce time.
    if (this.config.remote === true) {
      this.items = [];
    }
    this.searchSubject.next($event);
  }
```

**Controller**: On ngInit I subscribe on that event in order to fetch the new data:

```
// Inside ngOnInit I subscribe to the observable
this.searchSubject.debounceTime(500)
                  .takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe)
                  .subscribe( (searchTextValue: string) => {

  // save search string on scope
  this.searchTextValue = searchTextValue;
  this.config.httpParams = this.config.httpParams.set('search', searchTextValue);

  // only send search if more than x chars (or empty)
  if (searchTextValue === '' || searchTextValue.length >= this.config.minChars) {
    this.fetchResults();
  }
});
```

**Controller**: This is the method to fetch the results:

```
// fetchResult method fetches the new items and appends them to the items array
this.httpClient.get(url, {params: this.config.httpParams})
               .takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe)
               .subscribe( (res: any) => {

                 this.items = this.transformSelectableValuesToConsumables(res);

                 this.select.items = this.items;

                 this.loadingResults = false;
               },
               (error) => {
                 this.loadingResults = false;

                 // TODO: Implement proper error handling
               });
```

Everything works correctly with the object: items array is populated and filled correctly. However, The dropdown closes and opens only when I focus out and back in. Seems to be a bug in the component. I also raised an issue on their github:

https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-select/issues/929

Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now I found a solution.

In the callback, where you need to assign the new items, open the dropdown manually:

```
// fetchResult method fetches the new items and appends them to the items array
this.httpClient.get(url, {params: this.config.httpParams})
           .takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe)
           .subscribe( (res: any) => {

             this.items = this.transformSelectableValuesToConsumables(res);

             this.select.items = this.items;

             // [BUGFIX] Here we open the select manually
             (<any>this.select).open();

             this.loadingResults = false;
           },
           (error) => {
             this.loadingResults = false;

             // TODO: Implement proper error handling
           });
```

And remove the `[items]` assignment in the component template:

```
<ng-select
  #select 
  [allowClear]="'true'"
  id="DropdownTypeaheadQuestion-{{ question.id }}"
  [formControl]="formControlToUse"
  placeholder="{{ placeholderText }}"
  [multiple]="isMultiple"
  (selected)="execSelected($event)"
  (typed)="execKeypress($event)">
</ng-select>
```

So the items will purely be handled over the `@ViewChild` assignment in the controller.

Here's the entire solution: [Link](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-select/issues/635#issuecomment-281094377)